How can smartsheet-python-sdk be used to auto-populated the dropdown content in a Smartsheet
How can I automatically update the dropdown content (values) in Smartsheet column (set with dropdown property). I would like the dropdown content in my target Smartsheet updated based on the values inputted on a separate Smartsheet (Source Smartsheet).
Using smartsheet-python-sdk, i tried implementing the following code with no noticeable updates to the dropdown in the target sheet...
import smartsheet

# Initialize client
access_token = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(access_token)

# IDs of the source and target sheets
source_sheet_id = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
target_sheet_id = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
source_column_id = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
dropdown_column_id = 'XXXXXXXXXX'

# Defining this function to get unique values from the source sheet column
def get_unique_values(sheet_id, column_id):
    sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)
    values = set()
    for row in sheet.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            if cell.column_id == column_id and cell.value:
                values.add(cell.value)
    return list(values)

# Getting unique values from the source sheet
dropdown_values = get_unique_values(source_sheet_id, source_column_id)

# Updating the dropdown column in the target sheet
column = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_column(target_sheet_id, dropdown_column_id)
column.options = dropdown_values
updated_column = smartsheet_client.Sheets.update_column(target_sheet_id, dropdown_column_id, column)

# Visualizing the updates
print(f"Updated dropdown values: {updated_column.options}")


Without an error message I'm not positive, but I'm guessing the issue is that you're using the column object as an argument in the update_column() method. The error I get when I try to do that is:
..."errorCode": 1032, "message": "The attribute(s) column.id are not allowed for this operation."...

I just created a new column object using a dictionary from the target column object after removing the 'id' key-value pair from the dictionary. Here's the chunk of the code I'd update:

# Updating the dropdown column in the target sheet
column = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_column(target_sheet_id, dropdown_column_id)
column.options = dropdown_values
col_dict = column.to_dict()
col_dict.__delitem__('id')
new_column = smartsheet.models.Column(col_dict)
updated_column = smartsheet_client.Sheets.update_column(target_sheet_id, dropdown_column_id, new_column)


